# cmd line change "AllowRemoteRPC" value

Tags: cmd, command, line

I need to know how to change the value of `AllowRemoteRPC` on a remote (lan /domain) computer. I have tried the SC command:

```
sc \\%ComputerName% start "service"
```

but realized that I do not need to start the service because it is a binary value that needs to be changed from zero to one.

Any help would be appreciated. Also it is worth mentioning that I do not want to be doing this on my computer. **%ComputerName%** is the service tag of the unit I would like to interact with and I am using a SC command to turn on the remoteregistry successfully.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who prefer a GUI method:

Once you have started the Remote Registry service, you can also open Regedit.exe on your computer and click File -> Open Network Registry...

Enter the name of the computer to which you would like to connect and hit Enter.

Another node will show up with the HKLM and HKU nodes of the remote computer.  From there, expand HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server.

If you do not see "AllowRemoteRPC" in the pane to your right, you can right-click in a blank space in the right-hand pane and select New -> DWORD (32-bit) Value.  Name it "AllowRemoteRPC" (Minus the quotes), and hit Enter.  Double-click it or hit Enter while it is highlighted, and change the value to 1.

If I remember correctly, a reboot is necessary for the setting to become effective.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Okay if I'm understanding this right, you have access to the remote computer but you can't change the registry value. Use the command regsetval dword HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Sever "AllowRemoteRPC" "1". And that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server" /v "AllowRemoteRPC" /t "REG_DWORD" /d "1" /f
```

use .bat file or cmd